# Handle kafka messages due to transient error in DLQ

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, dlq

I am using `spring cloud stream kafka binding` and `resilience4j circuit breaker`. In cloud stream when `enableDlq: true` all messages with exception in processing goes to the `dlq` topic.

Now, lets suppose we have an `exponential backoff retry` configured to retry messages 5 times. But there is still a chance that due to some transient issue (dependent service going down), good messages fail even after all retries and goes in dlq.

Considering that situation, is there any proper way as how to retry the messages from the dlq topic.

Also please note that the consumer kafka broker might be an external service not in our control to produce back to the main topic as stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/4.1-SNAPSHOT/kafka/kafka-binder/dlq.html#_enabling_dlq)